# Neo4j -ogm-wildfly-cipher query not working

Tags: neo4j, wildfly

Below is a query and an exception which I am facing using Neo4j on Wildfly server:

```
1:08:29,088 INFO  [org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest] (default task-64) Request: match( root:EntityNode {modelId :'7b18b9b0-f77f-4957-b973-957ee421bead' , workspaceId : '8a08ecfc562102390156214405360000'}) OPTIONAL MATCH(root)-[r:HAS_ASSOCIATION]->(m) return root,r,m with params {}
11:08:32,146 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-64) Forwarding to error page from request [/resource/erDiagramXML/7b18b9b0-f77f-4957-b973-957ee421bead] due to exception [Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.]
```

The same thing is working on an embedded tomcat server in a spring boot application though. Can someone help?

Comment: How do you execute this query?

Comment: Below is the code                                                                              String entityQuery = "match(entity:EntityNode { modelId : '" + modelId + "' , workspaceId : '" + containerId
    + "'})-[relation : CONTAINS]- (root) " + "  return entity, root ";

  Iterable<EntityNode> resultSet = session.query(getNodeClass(), entityQuery, Collections.emptyMap());

Answer (score 1):

The exception says you must return one column (because of the way the query is executed):

> Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.

whereas your query returns 3:

```
return root,r,m
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the container running the application, but all to do with the actual queries executed.